# if Condition is True before it performs segue

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I am using segue for the transition from `ViewController B` going to `ViewController A` and at the same time I am using segue to pass data from `ViewController B` going to `ViewController A`. I already constructed my codes wherein the user will tapped the `backbutton` and executes an `alert controller` using `SCLAlertView cocoapods`. It prompts [image: this alert] before it proceeds to the next `ViewController`, but when I run it, the segue performs automatically without checking the condition first and it did not executes the `alert controller`. My codes are below for your reference.Hope you could help me regarding this because I am new in swift and I had my research but seems I can't see solution that is applicable in my issue. Thank you.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showVCA" {
        if let vc_A = segue.destination as? ViewControllerA {
            vc_A.validPincode = validPincode
            vc_A.participants = participants
            vc_A.event = event
        }
    }
}



 @IBAction func backbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = SCLAlertView(appearance: confirmationAppearance)
    _ = alert.addButton("Leave", action: {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showVCA", sender: sender)

    })
    _ = alert.addButton("Stay", action: { })
    _ = alert.showError("Confirmation", subTitle: "Are you sure you want to leave this page?")

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Validation should be done before `performSegue`, once you `performSegue` means you already execute the code to move to the next ViewController.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "showVCA" {
        if let vc_A = segue.destination as? ViewControllerA {
            vc_A.validPincode = validPincode
            vc_A.participants = participants
            vc_A.event = event
        }
    }
}



@IBAction func backbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let alert = SCLAlertView(appearance: confirmationAppearance)
    _ = alert.addButton("Leave", action: {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        if validation() {
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "showVCA", sender: sender)
        }

    })
    _ = alert.addButton("Stay", action: { })
    _ = alert.showError("Confirmation", subTitle: "Are you sure you want to leave this page?")

}

func validation() -> Bool {
     // add validation logic here
     return false
}
```

Comment: How will I construct it?

Comment: @Titus added validation sample

Comment: The preferred way to check whether a segue should be performed is to implement `UIViewController.shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)`.

Comment: @ZaidM.Said Hi how can I set the validation if the user tapped the `Leave` button in the alert controller . It will dismis ViewController B and performSegue? Sorry, I am really puzzled.

Comment: @Titus The validation should be done in current controller (in my example the code should be in function `validation()`) once the validation is done (return true), then `performSegue` will be executed.

Comment: @ZaidM.Said i really dont get it. sorry :(

Comment: @ZaidM.Said i tried to debug it but still the segue performs automaticcally

Comment: @Titus I've added `validation()` function which will do validation. Then I added `if validation()` to actually execute validation checking, if it is true, then `performSegue` gets called.

Comment: @ZaidM.Said even if I included validation before `performSegue` still, it automatically segue the other view controller :(

Comment: @NRitH how can I implement `UIViewController.shouldPerformSegue(withIdentifier:sender:)` ? Sorry, been trying it also but i don't know what will be the right approach to use it

Comment: `shouldPerformSegue` is no help here, because you want to display an Alert, which works asynchronously. You need to provide your own back button (not the one provided automatically by the `UINavigationController`) and do the stuff inside it's event handler, as to be seen in this answer.

Comment: @AndreasOetjen Hi the back button is not `UINavigationController`. What is the best solution for this?

Comment: So you see the alert, and (at the same time) the segue is performed? In this case, you should check the connetions of the back button (See answer from NRitH).

Answer (score 0):

Your `backbutton()` function doesn't appear to *present* the alert controller (by calling one of `SCLAlertView`'s many `showXXX()` functions), so nothing will ever be shown. And is it possible that your button is connected to your view controller's Exit instead of the action?

[image]